# Maven plugin for Java code obfuscation

Tags: java, android

Is there a maven plugin for obfuscating Java code (Java SE, Java EE or Android)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just googled "java obfuscator maven plugin" and found a lot of links including this one: http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/proguard-maven-plugin/

I think that you should choose the obfuscator that matches your needs first. If there is no maven plugin that wraps this obfuscator run it from maven pom.xml via command line.

Answer (score 1):

proguard-maven-plugin is the tool what you want.See this [link](http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/proguard-maven-plugin/) to details usages.